# How to display text dynamically on screen in Kivy using kivymd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to build a chatbot. I have built the UI and it has a input textfield and a button binded to the text field which when pressed generates a response according to the input given by the user. I store that response in a global variable named reply and I want to display that response on the screen.
I have used the following code snippet to do it but it doesn't work. (I assume it shows the inital value of the variable reply which is an empty string.)

```
text = MDLabel(text=reply,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.05})
screen.add_widget(text)
```

How to I make the screen widget update itself constantly so it displays the current value of the variable response.
Here's my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.lang import Builder
import helpers
from cbot import text
global reply
reply=""
class Bot(MDApp):
    def show_data(self,obj):
        question=self.username.text

        reply=text.chat.converse(question)
        print(reply)


    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        screen = Screen()

        self.input = Builder.load_string(helpers.textfield)
        button = MDIconButton(icon="chevron-double-right",pos_hint={'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.05},on_release=self.show_data)
        text = MDLabel(text=reply,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.05})

        screen.add_widget(self.input)
        screen.add_widget(button)
        screen.add_widget(text)

        return screen

print(reply)

Bot().run()
```

Comment: If you add your widgets in .kv file, Kivy automaticly upload their texts.But if you add widgets which is created in .py file , you need to re-add these widgets to your screen. So you need to use `remove_widget()` and `add_widget` .You should use new function to do it after each type or each second as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you save a reference to your `MDLabel` like this:

```
self.text = MDLabel(text=reply,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.05})
```

Then, in your `show_data()` method, you can do:

```
self.text.text = reply
```